# Why won't my scope item bind to this promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I have a scope declaration....

```
$scope.item = animalStore.query();
```

The animal store is like this...

```
factories.factory('animalStore', [
    '$resource','$q', function($resource,$q) {

        var resource = $resource("animals.json");
        return resource;

    }
]);
```

It works fine however....

I want to use a 'promise pattern' which I have used in other apps to make sure my data is not loaded twice. However my binding doesn't seem to work even though the data comes back fine in the 'then' call. I have checked the type of 'data' it is a promise/array so I should be able to bind my scope to it but can't why is this?

```
var globalPromise = null;
factories.factory('animalStore', [
    '$resource','$q', function($resource,$q) {

        var resource = $resource("animals.json");

        var retObj = new Object();
        retObj.query = function() {

            if (!globalPromise) {
                console.log('getting data');
                globalPromise = resource.query(function () { }).$promise;
            }

            globalPromise.then(function (data) {

                return data;
            });

        }

        return retObj;

    }
]);
```

On a side note are there any libraries that let me do this behaviour without having to write custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your factory you should return the promise from your function called `query`. As shown below.

```
return globalPromise.then(function (data) {
    return data;
});
```

Then in your controller you can assign the result to the `$scope.item` as below.

```
animalStore.query().then(function (data) {
    $scope.item = data;
});
```

Hope then helps.

Comment: Do I HAVE to wrap it in that ugly as sin then statement? I want to write clean code...Didn't angular used to do this automatically?

Comment: I believe this is the way I deal with promises in angular. Unless I have missed anything. Did this help to get the data back?

Comment: I think I was looking for a feature in angular called 'unwrapping' which they disabled in version 1.2. Anyway this helped thanks a lot.